# what does "up" means here in "what are you up to"

Tags: parts-of-speech

in sentence "what are you up to", what is the definition of "up" and what part of speech is it?

there are way too many definitions for "up", I am not sure which one "up" is using in above sentence.

does "up" has to be used together with "to" to work?

my question is, is "up" here a adjective or adverb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**be up to sth**
​

**to be doing something:**

*What are you up to at the moment?*

https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/be-up-to-sth

Comment: so it is an idiomatic expression

Comment: It is. At least where I live in the US.